# ftpwebrequest - FTP FileUpload - Rate Of Transfer

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am uploading a 10GB file to my ftp server using c# ftpwebrequest. How can the rate of transfer be calculated ?

The following is the code:

```
        FileStream fs = null;
        Stream rs = null;

        try
        {


            string uploadFileName = new FileInfo(file).Name;


            string uploadUrl = ftpServer;

            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: {0}", DateTime.Now);

            fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            string ftpUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uploadUrl, uploadFileName);
            FtpWebRequest requestObj = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl) as FtpWebRequest;

            requestObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            rs = requestObj.GetRequestStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[40960];

            int read = 0;
            while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                rs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            rs.Flush();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File upload/transfer Failed.\r\nError Message:\r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
            }

            if (rs != null)
            {
                rs.Close();
                rs.Dispose();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End Time: {0}", DateTime.Now);

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting the application.. press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The upload speed was low so I bumped up the Buffer Size to 40960 after referring to some articles. The speed has increased a bit.

Please explain the solution as well for my understanding as I am a beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: exactly the same way you calculate speed of a car or anything else.. over a specified amount of time you traveled x so if in 1 minute you've downloaded 60mb, you're doing 1mb/s ..

Comment: Probably need some multithreading in this...